# How to create Android EC2 AMI from scratch?

Tags: android-emulator, cloud, genymotion

I've tested all [Genymotion on-Demand AMIs](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/seller-profile?id=933724b4-d35f-4266-905e-e52e4792bc45), but they doesn't work for me, since some apps are not compatible with 64-bit platform.

I'd like to create my own x86 (32-bit) AMI where I can install [The Open GApps](http://opengapps.org/), then install some other apps. What would be a good starting point to do that?

Comment: How is this of interest to Android end-users?

Comment: Site is for 'users of the Android operating system', and Genymotion emulator is using it. You've also tag for Genymotion, so I don't see the problem here about sharing the knowledge about Android and Genymotion stuff. I'm also the end-user playing with Android apps in Genymotion emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save compile times of the entire Android OS (see: [Requirements](https://source.android.com/source/requirements) and [Building of Android OS](https://source.android.com/source/building)) and your custom ROM builds from hours, it is possible to use [Android Open Source Project AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01FL0MMW2) as a starting point for building the entire AOSP build environment which is pre-configured and completely synced with the repo on this app and ready to go.

Once the instance is ready, run these commands to compile the Android OS:

```
$ cd aosp && . build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch aosp_arm-BUILDTYPE
$ make -j4
```

The `BUILDTYPE` is one of the following:

- `user`: limited access; suited for production,
- `userdebug`: like "user", but with root access,
- `eng`: development configuration with additional debugging tools.

<sup>See: [Preparing to build](https://source.android.com/source/building).</sup>

The solution above eliminates the need to host a build environment on the local machine, or require the Linux OS.